# ERROR: Error installing mysql: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems

I am a beginner  in ruby.
when I install MySQL in gem,I got a problem which confused me a long time.
I install MySQL from brew, as you know the computer system is OSX 10.10.
I have try all solution that can found in stackoverflow,but can't solve it.
such as:

```
 1. Install xcode-tool
 2. GEM  install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a
 3. List itgem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25ae
```

and so on....

The question is:
When I code the command:`gem install mysql`
I got the below error:

```
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
/Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:720:in `try_func'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1004:in `block in have_func'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/iclick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1003:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:45:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/iclick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@style/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/iclick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@style/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out
```

Forgiving my poor english.^_^.
Hoping your answer.

Answer (score 0):

happy,i have solved the problem.
when i execute the command `gem update`.i got a error,then,i think the issue is caused by gem.
so,i execute the command `gem get stable`.and then execute the command `brew unlink libyaml && brew link libyaml` and mysql is installed successful!!!